# A $3\times 3$ matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if all of its $2\times 2$ submatrices are positive semidefinite$?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, semidefinite-programming

Is it true that a $3\times 3$ Hermitian matrix, $A$, is positive semidefinite if and only if all of its $2\times 2$ submatrices are positive semidefinite$?$

First consider the ordered set of projectors that project out a single axis 
$$P=\left(I-e_1e_1^T,I-e_2e_2^T,I-e_3e_3^T \right)$$

I can write the identity matrix as the following:
$$I = \frac{1}{2} \left(P_1+P_2+P_3 \right) $$

Now the condition in order for my 3x3 matrix, A, to be semidefinite is:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^TAx \ge0$$

Inserting the identity matrix on both sides:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^TAx=x^TIAIx \ge0$$

and expanding out my definition of the identity.

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^TAx=\frac{1}{4}x^T\left(P_1+P_2+P_3 \right)A\left(P_1+P_2+P_3 \right)x \ge0$$

Expanding the product we get:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^TP_1AP_1x+x^TP_1AP_2x+x^TP_1AP_3x+x^TP_2AP_1x+x^TP_2AP_2x+x^TP_2AP_3x+x^TP_3AP_1x+x^TP_3AP_2x+x^TP_3AP_3x\ge0$$

Exploiting the hermiticity of A and the projection matrices we can rewrite the above as:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^TP_1AP_1x+2x^TP_1AP_2x+2x^TP_1AP_3x+x^TP_2AP_2x+2x^TP_2AP_3x+x^TP_3AP_3x\ge0$$

Now I believe that through the various projections each term in this sum can be independently varied with particular choices in the variation of X.  Since each term in the sum is independent of the others, the inequality distributes over each term in the sum.

$$\leftrightarrow \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^3:x^TP_1AP_1x \ge0 \cap x^TP_1AP_2x \ge0 \cap x^TP_1AP_3x \ge0 \cap x^TP_2AP_2x \ge0 \cap x^TP_2AP_3x \ge0 \cap  x^TP_3AP_3x \ge0$$

Since each term above is a 3x3 matrix with a 2x2 submatrix and the rest of the entries zero, this implies that every 2x2 submatrix of A is positive semidefinite if and only if A is positive semidefinite.

Is my reasoning sound or is the sleep deprivation kicking in?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a perturbed $3 \times 3$ non positive definite matrix that has all $1$ on the diagonal and all $-1 + \epsilon$ on the off-diagonal, for some small $\epsilon > 0$. Can you see how the determinant of this matrix is negative (so not positive semi-definite), and yet every time you choose two indices $i,j$ for the two rows and the same two indices for the two columns, you get a positive definite $2 \times 2$ matrix? Or do you mean something else by "all $2 \times 2$ submatrices are positive definite"? It would seem strange to not choose the same indexed rows as indexed columns for a matrix when trying to show something like this, but let me know if I'm wrong.

As a side note, if you're wondering how to come up with an example like this, I have a bit of stats background so I think of $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrices as being equivalently defined as "covariance matrices", where entry $a_{ij}$ in the matrix defines the covariance (scaled correlation) between variables $i$ and $j$. If variables $i,j$ are strongly negatively correlated, and so are variables $i,k$, then variables $j,k$ should have at least some positive correlation, by composition of correlation trends. So a non-covariance symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix can easily be obtained by setting all diagonal entries to a positive constant and then setting all off-diagonal entries to be nearly as large negative constants.

Comment: Ok lets call your counter-example matrix, B and let $b=\epsilon-1$.  I calculated $Det[B]=2b^3-3b^2+1=(b-1)^2(2b+1)$

Comment: Ok going through the submatrices now.  Let $SB[i,j] \mapsto P_iBP_j$

Comment: I will utilize the theorem that a 2 x 2 matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if its Trace and Determinant are greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: $$SB[1,1]=\left(\begin{matrix} 
1 & b \\
b & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$Tr[SB[1,1]]=2$$
$$Det[SB[1,1]]=1-b^2$$

Comment: For reference:
$$B=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & b & b \\
b &1 & b \\
b & b & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: $$SB[1,2]=\left(\begin{matrix}
b & b \\
b & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$Tr[SB[1,2]]=b+1$$
$$Det[SB[1,2]]=b-b^2=b(1-b)$$

Comment: $$SB[1,3]=\left(\begin{matrix}
b & b \\
1 & b \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$Tr[SB[1,3]]=2b$$
$$Det[SB[1,3]]=b^2-b=-b(1-b)=b(b-1)$$

Comment: @user118494  I believe my positive semidefinite conditions for SB[1,2] and SB[1,3] constrain your B matrix down to two trivial cases.

I have:
$$Det[SB[1,2]]=b(1-b) \ge 0$$
$$Det[SB[1,3]]=-b(1-b) \ge 0$$

Both of these imply that:
 $$b=0 \cup b=1 $$
$$\rightarrow B=I \cup B=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$\rightarrow Det[B]=1 \cup Det[B]=0$$  

And these two specific and trivial cases imply that B is positive semidefinite, otherwise your counterexample matrix will fail my tests.

Shall I continue with more submatrices?

Comment: (see above) do you spot anything wrong with my calculations?  Should I continue with more submatrices.

Comment: its funny that you brought this up as the specific application  I am trying to use this for is detecting whether the smallest principal component is greater than or equal to a certain threshold value while trying to get the order of the polynomials I have to calculate as small as possible.

Comment: According to the way I'm used to computing $2 \times 2$ submatrices $SB[i,j]$, I would get that all the $SB[I,j]$ are equal, with 1's on the diagonal and $b$'s on the off diagonal. This is because the way I define $SB[i,j]$, you choose the same two indices $I,j$ for rows as you do for columns, and get the 4 entries that have these pairs of indices. In particular, the diagonal is always a subset of the original diagonal, and off-diagonal is a subset of the original off-diagonal. If your $P_i B P_j$ defining $SB[i,j]$ is different then maybe your claim is true.

Comment: I am defining SB[i,j] to be the submatrix resulting from removing the ith column and the jth row.  I hope that helps.

Comment: @CavanStone In that case, you can come up with a symmetric positive definite $3 \times 3$ matrix such that $SB[1,3]$ has negative determinant. For this, define the diagonal to be $1$, and then $a_{13} = a_{31} = 1/2$ and all other entries $0$. So if your $2 \times 2$ conditions imply positive semi definite $3 \times 3$, then the implication only goes one way